# How to convert a .doc to .pdf with field lock via powershell

Tags: pdf, powershell, ms-word

I am looking to convert all .doc documents that end up in a specific folder. This part I have covered (see below code). The issue that I am having is there is a field that is inside of the document itself that breaks every time you try to save the document as a different file type. If you highlight the field and lock it (CRTL + F11) then save works like a champ. If you have any ideas at all please let me know. I am willing to try anything out at this point in time.

```
$wdFormatPDF = 17
$word = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$word.visible = $false
$folderpath = "c:\test\*"
$fileTypes = "*.doc"
Get-ChildItem -path $folderpath -include $fileTypes |
foreach-object `
{
 $path =  ($_.fullname).substring(0,($_.FullName).lastindexOf("."))
 "Converting $path to pdf ..."
 $doc = $word.documents.open($_.fullname)
 $doc.saveas([ref] $path, [ref]$wdFormatPDF)
$doc.close()
}
$word.Quit()
```

Comment: Is this actually specific to how PowerShell is invoking the MS Word COM objects or does the same behavior exhibit itself if you open the document on your desktop and perform the save as manually? Are you really asking for help automating the task of selecting all the fields and locking them?

Comment: Same behavior in ps and manually. I finally ended up creating a macro that locks those formats when word opens. Seems to work?

Answer (score 0):

After you grab the filename and remove extension you didn't append .pdf to to it.

```
$path =  ($_.fullname).substring(0,($_.FullName).lastindexOf("."))
 "Converting $path to pdf ..."
```

You are missing this line

```
$path = $path + ".pdf"


## $doc = $word.documents.open($_.fullname)
 $doc.saveas([ref] $path, [ref]$wdFormatPDF)
```

If that doesn't help then $doc has Fields.Locked Property which you set it to True or False.

```
$doc.Fields.Locked = $true
```